# C# Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, reference, namespaces

What reference do I have to add to use "Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video"?
It is not recognized currently.

Answer (score 2):

You find the [`Video`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb281556(VS.85).aspx) in microsoft.directx.audiovideoplayback.dll. Unless you're aware of it though, the Managed DirectX product is no longer supported and is superseded by [Microsoft XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791.aspx).

Comment: I found the Video link, but I don't hv to dll file. So I went to search for the dll file. I found it, and my code and compile, but it can't work! No error nothing... Microsoft XNA? How do I start using it?

Comment: Currently I just want a simple piece of code where I can get the duration of the video, sth like this: http://bellouti.wordpress.com/2007/09/28/determine-a-video-size/ But this doesn't work.

Comment: XNA is (currently) not very suited to load arbitrary video streams for playback... Perhaps raising a new question with your real goal is an idea?

Comment: i just want something to get the duration of a video file, nothing much at the moment.

Comment: My new qn here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445939/how-do-i-get-the-duration-of-a-video-file-using-c

Comment: Ook, sure it wasn't just the DX runtime you were missing? you shouldn't need the whole SDK just to run the MDX libraries...

Answer (score 0):

You need to download DirectX SDK.

After you install the SDK, you'll be able to reference it.

"DirectX Software Development Kit" from Microsoft Download Center