# How do I get the duration of a video file using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, video

Any library in C# that allows me to do that?

Comment: Does it matter? For eg wmv...

Comment: Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256841/c-get-video-file-duration-from-metadata

Comment: Because tt qn don't hv a sol to it! And i don't hv LoaderLock exception... I managed to get the right way to use Direct X after figuring out tt i need the SDK for it. Below got another sol, i wonder if it is better than Direct X?

Answer (score 4):

google result for http://johndyer.name/post/2005/07/22/Retreiving-the-duration-of-a-WMV-in-C.aspx

```
using WMPLib; // this file is called Interop.WMPLib.dll

WindowsMediaPlayerClass wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
IWMPMedia mediaInfo = wmp.newMedia("myfile.wmv"); 

// write duration
Console.WriteLine("Duration = " + mediaInfo.duration);

// write named attributes
for (int i=0; i<mediaInfo.attributeCount; i++)
{
Console.WriteLine(mediaInfo.getAttributeName(i) + " = " +  mediaInfo.getItemInfo(mediaInfo.getAttributeName(i)) );
}
```

Comment: Where do I find Interop.WMPLib.dll? Can I use the above for files other than wmv? I was just quoting an eg, i need more files of different format.

Comment: I'd assume you could use this for any file format your installed version of windows media player will open, but you'd have to test it. I doubt you'll find a library which will handle EVERY format.

Look at the bottom of this link for instruction on how to wrap wmp.dll if it's not on your system...
http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/topic62074.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Extension method.

```
using Shell32;

public static class Extension
{
    public static string GetLength(this FileInfo info)
    {
        var shell = new ShellClass();
        var folder = shell.NameSpace(info.DirectoryName);
        var item = folder.ParseName(info.Name);

        return folder.GetDetailsOf(item, 27);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code snippet will help you :

```
using WMPLib;
// ...your code here...

var player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
var clip = player.newMedia(filePath);
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(clip.duration));
```

> and don't forget to add the reference of **`wmp.dll`** which will be
>   present in **`System32`** folder.