# Reading WMV resolution in C#

Tags: c#, wmv

I'm trying to read the image size of a WMV file in C#.
I've tried using what is described here:
[How do I get the duration of a video file using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445939/how-do-i-get-the-duration-of-a-video-file-using-c)
but the only attribute that has a value is Duration.

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to play the file, or just get the header information?

Comment: I don't need to play it, just get the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I've seen it done is by playing it and attaching to the open event:

```
    static WindowsMediaPlayerClass player;

    static void Main()
    {
        player = new WindowsMediaPlayerClass();  
        IWMPMedia mediaInfo = player.newMedia("test.wmv");
        player.OpenStateChange += new _WMPOCXEvents_OpenStateChangeEventHandler(player_OpenStateChange);
        player.currentMedia = mediaInfo;

        //...

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void player_OpenStateChange(int state)
    {
        if (state == (int)WMPOpenState.wmposMediaOpen)
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "height = " + player.currentMedia.imageSourceHeight);
            Console.WriteLine( "width = " + player.currentMedia.imageSourceWidth);
        }
    }
```

You'll want to dispose of any resources before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

You use the code from the linked example, but you explicitly do a function call to get the [height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563438(v=VS.85).aspx) and [width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563439(v=VS.85).aspx).

Example:

```
using WMPLib; // this file is called Interop.WMPLib.dll

WindowsMediaPlayerClass wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
IWMPMedia mediaInfo = wmp.newMedia("myfile.wmv"); 

long height, width;
mediaInfo.get_imageSourceHeight(height);
mediaInfo.get_imageSourceWidth(width);
```

Comment: That does not compile:
'WMPLib.IWMPMedia.imageSourceHeight.get': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor

Comment: and mediaInfo.imageSourceHeight returns zero.

Comment: He's right: unless the file is **playing**, imageSourceHeight and imageSourceWidth return 0.

Comment: It seems like such a simple thing, yet after a few hours of digging and trying I am no where closer to solving this.
There is almost no documentation about these classes, its very sad.
Playing the file is not simple, the application does not have a Form.

Anyone has any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the free NReco.VideoInfo.dll.  Mainly because I hate Windows Media Player.  I have found that WMP is unreliable.

Here is the download link: http://www.nrecosite.com/video_info_net.aspx  It's useful for other stuff too.

```
var ffProbe = new NReco.VideoInfo.FFProbe();
var videoInfo = ffProbe.GetMediaInfo(pathToFile);
Int32 tmpHeight = videoInfo.Streams[0].Height;
Int32 tmpWidth = videoInfo.Streams[0].Width;
```